# Slow down video playing

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, mplayer

I was wondering how to slow down video playing in VLC Player and in MPlayer Movie Player.

Answer (score 2):

In MPlayer, I use SMPlayer fronted, `[` does the job. VLC is the same. (Checked, same goes for MPlayer.)